# What is the most comfortable work space?

Tags: work-environment, company-culture, travel

Im looking for a bit of feedback from programmers about work spaces.

Is it common to work in different areas throughout the day? (Coffee Shops, Coworking Spaces, Hotels, Trains, etc.)

What are the 3 most necessary pieces of equipment while working?

Thanks!
-Sam

Comment: "Your questions should be reasonably scoped... avoid asking subjective questions where …

    every answer is equally valid" ([help/dont-ask])

Comment: Thanks Gnat, do you think with these changes I can get a more natural response?

Comment: Voting to close because the answers will all be a matter of subjective preferences. For example, I can shut out the world around me and I'll be  comfortable working next to a jackhammer. Somebody might not stand even a low key conversation in the neighboring workspace.

Comment: This is true, the answers will be subjective. I purely want to gain insight on different ways to work that people have tried.

Comment: way too broad... The last alone, some would say coffee to all 3, myself I'm more inclined to tea.

Comment: "This site is all about getting answers. **It's not a discussion forum.** There's no chit-chat..." ([tour])

Comment: You should search (not post this question) [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)  There's a lot of information on these subjects. Some are questions that have been closed, but they may be of some help to you.

Comment: I don't see why this is seen as a discussion in the first place, I am not promoting conversation, simply wanting responses for my questions. Both questions look to see what the majority of users decide, for example if more users upvote that they work from one spot that is the answer I'm looking for. Additionally, there can be a consensus that a keyboard, cup of coffee and pair of headphones are the 3 most used items from all users, this is not a firm fact but it will answer my question.

Comment: "What are the 3 most necessary pieces..." => [polling for opinions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opinion_poll)

Comment: You are right^ I apologize for wasting everyones time on my question.

Comment: @SamWesley the question isn't a good fit for the Q&A format, *but* you are welcome to come into [chat] (where things are much looser) and talk with folks!  Normally using chat requires 20 reputation, but I've given you explicit access to our main room.  Please feel free to visit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a difficult one to give a definitive answer to as everyone is different.  Basically there are three types as far as I'd see, everything is a variation on these:

- Private space - office, home etc
- shared space - open plan office, shared workspace
- public - coffee shops, libraries, parks etc

It can vary by a lot what is acceptable to an individual, I've mainly worked in shared spaces (mostly open plan offices), some of which could be described as like a crèche, or in one case, downtown Beirut.  As a result I can tune out the ambient (sometimes people need to tap me on the shoulder to show they are actually talking to me).

As regards what is necessary equipment, 3 things for me are:

1. light weight computer - actually use a 3g chromebook as much as possible, remote desktop onto a VDI if I need some power (I can access servers and power developer desktops).  Lets me work anywhere, and move if required.
2. Headphones and mobile - bluetooth full closed Sony headphones, good sound for music, plus I can do calls, even take a stroll whilst locked in a never-ending conference call.
3. Aladdin thermos cafetiere - make fresh coffee and keep it hot and drinkable, record is 6 hrs - can either plunge my fresh coffee or plunger unscrews for a coffee shop brew.